# How can I force compilation error in VS 2015 code analyzer ("light bulb")

Tags: visual-studio-2015

So i did create a new template project in Visual Studio 2015 from the "Analyzer with Code Fix template". 
I did some small modification to it that does show potential code fix for each property in the code. The code fix is simply appending some postfix to the name of the property.

This works, the lightbulb is shown with a potential code fix suggestion, however, the compilation ends with success (which is obvious).

I would like to extend it to make the compilation fail as long as the property stays with it's original name.

I couldn't find any source on how I could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Menu "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..."
2. Tab "Browse"
3. Type in text field: "Microsoft.ApiDesignGuidelines.Analyzers"
4. Select all projects (or just some projects)
5. Click "Install"

Then, in solution explorer, expand in a project: "References" > "Analyzers" > "Microsoft.ApiDesignGuidelines.Analyzers", right click on a rule, "Set Rule Set Severity" and set "Error" severity.

[image]